# FX swap implied yield from bloomberg

Tags: interest-rates, fx, derivatives, swaps

I am trying to reproduce the **bid** EUR implied yield I see in the screenshot below for 1y tenor which is -0.6226%.

EUR implied yield bid = spot_bid/fwd_bid *(1+i_USD_bid) - 1

Inputs from BBG terminal:

1y USD yield bid = 0.1962%

1y fwd_bid = 1.204757

spot bid = 1.1949

EUR implied yield bid = 1.1949/1.204757*(1+0.1962%) - 1 = -0.6236% which is different from -0.6226% I see on the terminal. Is this just rounding or I am missing anything?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe there's a Bloomberg manual in the help function which explicitly shows these calculations in a spreadsheet, very useful:

[image]